# get current menu position

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Is there a way to get the current menu position of a cardScrollView?

I call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` when Swipe_Left and Swipe_Right gestures are recognized.

I tried using the following code

```
@Override
public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId,View view, Menu menu)
{
    menu.clear();
    mPosition = mCardScroller.getSelectedItemPosition();
    Log.i("swiped", Integer.toString(mPosition));
    switch(mPosition)
    {
        case 0:
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu_0, menu);
            break;
        case 1:
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu_1, menu);
            break;
        case 2:
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu_2, menu);
            break;
    }

    return super.onPreparePanel(featureId, view, menu);
}
```

however `mCardScroller.getSelectedItemPosition();` gets the position that is active before swiping. I need a way to get this position after the swipe and that still makes sure the menu is inflated again so the menu is being shown for the appropriate card.

I tried using -1 and +1 as well only problem with this is when I do a hard swipe so it skips a few cards the number won't be correct anymore.

Does anyone know about a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CardScrollView's `onItemSelectedListener` to implement the `onItemSelected` callback method. This method is called when scrolling through a list has finished. For more details refer to the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html).

Comment: I don't think that solves my problem at all. onItemSelected needs a parameters like `adapterview, view, position, id` in the call. If I would know what the position was I wouldn't have this problem

Comment: It's a callback method that GDK will call after an item has been selected (made possible because of the listener). You will not call it yourself. Once it is called, you will have access to those parameters.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say now. However I have that implemented and I don't seem to be able to access the parameters. I might be overthinking it tho. Currently I fixed it by calling a runnable class that waits a few miliseconds after I swiped to another card to call `getSelectedItemPosition()` which causes me to get the correct position. but I think it's kind of a dirty fix and can't possibly be the best way to go